# Multi language support for application , mfc

Tags: mfc, multilingual

I have made windows MFC application which currently has English language only. What i want to do is give support for other languages also(E.G: Adobe on new language selection makes every text of application in that language.).

I have a clue for this , that i have to make resource.dll and use it according to selected language or checking for systems current language and select that language. But I am wondering on this 2 points.

1. How to create this resource dll
2. How to use this resource dll.

I require this because in future if i want to add more language support for my application i have to just create a resource dll and just upload that.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to take a look at [localizing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fkteez0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) your resources.  the first step in that is creating a [resource only dll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24b2tcy0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: I am successfully able to make the Newresource.dll and even implemented in my code but my problem is the application still shows the menu in english where as my NewResource.dll has japanese in it.Here is the code `HINSTANCE hInst   = NULL;
  if(!m_hInstLang){
   m_hInstLang = LoadLibrary(_T("LangExtension.dll"));
  }
   hInst = m_hInstLang;
   if(hInst)
  AfxSetResourceHandle(hInst);
 else
  AfxSetResourceHandle(m_hInstLang);` What might be the problem ?

Comment: What am I missing here?  If the NewResource.dll contains Japanese, why are you loading "LangExtension.dll"?

Comment: In the code for testing i just gave name to dll file as "LangExtension.dll" this file has the japanese language.

Comment: Please step through your code and check return codes from the functions that set up your resource dll.  Then, use the debugger to check that the correct resource dll is loaded (eg. debug/windows/modules) and its handle is the active resource dll.